# Cleaning the memory that Stockfish uses without closing the main program

Tags: c++, memory-management, stockfish

I am trying to implement Stockfish to my own project by a static library. But I have encountered a problem. Stockfish uses some global variables in the namespace of "Stockfish" and at somepoint in my project I want to destroy everything that I use from Stockfish and re-initialize later.

For example, Stockfish stores the options in a global object at Stockfish::Options. When I initialzie Stockfish for the first time everything is okay. But what I want to achieve it ending Stockfish and delete all members of it from variable without closing my project and reinitialize it whenever I want.

As far as I understand, Stockfish is not designed for that. It is desigend for "Start the engine, end the engine when the main program is closed.".

So, I believe I had to go through every initialization and find the proper ways to end them. Before doing that I wanted to ask that three questions:

- Can I tell my program to clean the memory that "this spesific .lib" uses?
- Can I write a code that deletes the entire memory that initialized by a namespace? For example, since Stockfish is the namespace for entire code, can I do something like "delete Stockfish;" ?
- Is there any other way that I cannot think to achieve what I want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tooling doesn’t make it easy to free the memory used by a specific library.

- Static library boundaries are not recorded, and do not exist at runtime (except maybe in debug symbols).
- The allocator does not generally record *where* an allocation was made.
- The same is true of namespaces. Namespaces do not exist at runtime, except in debug symbols. You cannot refer to a namespace.

There are two straightforward solutions:

1. Run Stockfish in a separate process. When the process exits, all memory is freed. This is the easy way.
2. Modify Stockfish so you can free the memory. Find all global state and all allocations, and make sure that you can free those allocations and reset the global state to the initial value. This is the hard way.

Comment: Oh I see... Just asking, would using dll instead of lib work? Can I load the dll whenever I want and close it? Will this clean up the memory too?

Comment: You can unload a DLL, but that doesn’t unload the memory that the DLL allocated.